# Executing sql in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to create tables in sqlite android development. My problem is, only one table is beaing created but the other one is not.

Here's how I create them.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        try
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE2);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Variables:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table if not exists profiles (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "firstname VARCHAR not null, age VARCHAR not null, " 
    + "heightft VARCHAR not null, heightin VARCHAR not null, weight VARCHAR not null, duration VARCHAR not null, bmi VARCHAR not null);";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE2 =
        "create table if not exists routines (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "weightclass VARCHAR not null, musclegroup VARCHAR not null, " 
        + "exercise VARCHAR not null, numberofsets VARCHAR not null, numeberofrepitition VARCHAR not null, day VARCHAR not null);";
```

Any ideas on what the problem is? Thanks!

Update:

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "fgtDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "profiles";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "routines";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        try
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
                    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE2);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS profiles");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you have first created one table, and added another table when the database is created.
If it is the case try to change the database version, because the onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) method is only called once, if the version is the same.

Comment: So meaning everytime that I will create a new table to my database, I need to change the database version? See my updated post, I'm setting a static final variable for the version. So I need to alter it to a changeable variable and do what you said? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: And I think it doesn't matter if it is called just once, since my code in the onCreate supposedly creates two tables. I don't see why one table is only created,

Comment: Yes. Another way to do it is to completely delete the database.

Comment: @ljpv14, did you change the version and check again?

Comment: I'm currently trying this, unistalling my app at the emulator and installing a fresh copy of the app. Since you said that I already created the database and added a new table to it. So as to remove the option to change a version, I'm uninstalling and reinstalling it.

Comment: FYI you can delete the database using DDMS -> File explorer under data/data your database

Comment: Tried that by pressing "-" in the DDMS but the database won't delete, so that's how I delete my database.